# How can I see previously uploaded Lambda .NET code

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda

I've been working on some Lambda functions using .NET Core 3.1 a while ago. I don't have their source codes anymore, and I need them. How can I obtain it from the AWS Console?
I tried to "Export" and download, but the generated .zip does not contain any recognizable (.cs/solution) files.
If anyone can lead me in the right direction, I'll be very grateful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you shouldn't have lost the source code. The best you have is the compiled code it seems, so you'll need something like Reflector/ILDASM

Comment: I do agree: I shouldn't have lost it.
Thanks for your input, I'll look into those options right away.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your post, the Lambda in question was developed with C# and deployed using the zip file process, as opposed to the newer requirement of a Docker image.

When the code to execute a Lambda is uploaded to the AWS Lambda, the zip file contains the necessary dll's to execute the process. In other words, the raw C# has been compiled into dll's, and you have no access to the original source files. You now only have access to the zip file with the deployed dll's.

The only option is to use a tool like [.NET Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), or similar to decompile the source code. However, the source code will not look exactly as originally written. Rather, the source code will be re-written with different syntax, but the logic will remain the same.